# TKCustomMap Version Conflict

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

This issue has been reported on GitHub here -

https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/issues/325

Has anyone else has struggled with this? I was stoked to find this nuget package because it does exactly what I'm looking for but it needs Places and some other GooglePlayServices installed and I can't install them because of this conflict.

I'm also not sure if uninstalling TK.CustomMap and then installing the Play Services would even help because the person who reported the issue on GitHub said-

---

I converted my app to .net 2.0 and had to use the newest Google play services 
60.1142.1 for AdMob to work. It wouldn't install until I uninstalled TK.CustomMap, and now TK.CustomMap won't reinstall because it only want to use GooglePlayServices 42.1021.1

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
HunterTracker.Android -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks (= 60.1142.1)
HunterTracker.Android -> HunterTracker -> TK.CustomMap 2.0.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 42.1021.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks (= 42.1021.1).

---

That's pretty much the exact error I'm getting trying to install the other packages. There's no resolution on github.

Anybody found a work around? Or does anyone know how to *"Reference the package directly from the project"*?

Comment: Just download that repo and update it dependancies manually and rebuild it, then use the resulting assemblies in your solution.

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty new to VS. After I download and update how do I find the assemblies and use them in the solution?

Comment: Assuming you build it you release mode, there will be bin/Release directories in each the project directories, one for iOS, Android, UWP....

Comment: Then you just copy the contents of the bin folder from that project into the new one and then include them in the solution at build?

Comment: Add a "Reference" to those assemblies, matching the referenced assembly to the project type... the Android assembly to your Xamarin.Android project, iOS to the iOs project, ....

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much for the information. Would you happen to have a link to a good tutorial on how to do this you could share?

Comment: Thanks dude. I was able to pull this off because you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to SushiHangover's comments above pointing me in the right direction I was able to discover what I needed to do here. I had an error updating the nuget packages of TK.CustomMap at first because v26 `Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable` was targeting `MonoAndroid8.0` and the update to v27 must target `MonoAndroid8.1` So it took quite a bit just to be able to update the nuget packages in order to get the assemblies with later versions so I could use TK.CustomMap in my solution. But I was eventually able to get there. Here were the steps I followed (as best I can remember). I am unable to compile ios right now because I don't have a MAC so that fix will have to come later. This fix is for the shared project and Android project only

1. Download the TK.CustomMap-master from github
2. Extract it and delete the Sample project completely (I also deleted the UWP project as I'm not really interested in that at this time)
3. Opened and built then closed. Deleted packages folder, vs folder, bin and obj from Android and Shared Project (this step is probably not necessary but I did it so...)
4. In the packages.config in Android changed all targets from `monoandroid80` to `monoandroid81` save file
5. In the TK.CustomMap.Android.csproj for every v26.0.1 of any Xamarin.Android.Support or other Xamarin.Android util package changed `26.0.1\lib\MonoAndroid80` to `27.0.2.1\lib\MonoAndroid81` - save file
6. In the nuget folder in TK.CustomMap.nuspec changed the target framework in this section

   ```
         <group targetFramework="lib\MonoAndroid7.0">
           <dependency id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" version="42.1021.1" />
           <dependency id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places" version="42.1021.1" />
           <dependency id="Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils" version="0.5.0" />
           <dependency id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.5.0.91635" />
           <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
         </group>
   ```

to

```
          <group targetFramework="lib\MonoAndroid">
```

so it could target any version

7. Opened and updated all nuget packages using package manager (not console). Built debug and release builds

At this point opened solution I had tried to implement TK.CustomMap in previously to attempt the fix. Remember the original issues was that the latest frameworks could not be used and 42.1021.1 frameworks were unable to locate `com.google.gms.location` and `com.google.gms.places.ui` files so they had to be updated or no TK.CustomMap

8. In the problem solution uninstalled TK.CustomMap from all projects
9. In the problem solution Android project added reference to all the dlls in the release folder of the Android bin file from TK.CustomMap project.
10. Installed updates for all Xamarin.Android frameworks in problem solution through Package Manager (not console)
11. Installed updates of all other nuget packages for all projects using Package Manager (not console)
12. Installed TK.CustomMap to Shared project using Package Manager (not console)
13. Added the References to the android project a second time. May or may not have helped.
14. Installed TK.CustomMap Nuget Package using Package Manager (not console)
15. Built and ran on Live Player successfully!!

Thanks to Sushi Hangover for the advice. I haven't seen any comprehensive tutorials anywhere on how to accomplish this so I figured I would post my own answer in case anyone else was looking. Definitely if you are new to VS all this stuff is no walk in the park in the beginning.

Comment: You can't know how much i love you.  This shit error appeared to me from days ago and after going the sequence to face it I ended in this post. You leaded me to the right way too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Travis Fleenor. This is my solution. I change a bit your sequence in order to work on mine.
 1. Make sure the original proyect from github (https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) works and you can run it.
 2. Update the nugets where you get the conflict. In my case I got conflicted in googleplay library version. I updated it in the original proyect and then assure it could run it.
 3. Compile entire solution in release mode. Then, copied the generated dll from bin/release and pasted them in a folder in my desktop. 
 4. I referenced those dll to shared proyect and android proyect. I only used nuget package manager to install some missing packages needed for the tk.custom. Notice that you only will reference some dll that the proyect accept. For the mayority Visual will prompt ' dll already referenced' something.
 5. first reference your shared proyect, later your android one. That's all. make sure the you ca recompile solution. 
 Hope this helps